# Kafka Connect custom SMT arvo serialization exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I am writing my own SMT that do some cleansing on a specific fields.

The code structure is straightforward, compiled and added to the `plugin.path` successfully.

When I create a connector with the following configuration

```
{
    "name": "sql-to-kafka", 
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector", 
        "database.hostname": "127.0.0.1", 
        "database.port": "3306", 
        "database.user": "username", 
        "database.password": "password", 
        "database.server.id": "11111", 
        "database.include.list": "test", 
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092", 
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schemahistory.localdb", 
        "include.schema.changes": "false",
        "database.encrypt": false,
        "table.include.list": "test.bins",
        "topic.prefix":"localdb",
        "transforms":"unwrap,MyCustomSMT",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": false,
        "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "drop",
        "transforms.MyCustomSMT.type": "MyCustomSMT$Value",
        "transforms.MyCustomSMT.field": "segment"
    }
}
```

I got the below exception in the connector logs

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:220)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.convertTransformedRecord(WorkerSourceTask.java:329)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:358)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:271)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:200)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:255)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to serialize Avro data from topic localdb.test.bins :
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:93)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:63)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$3(WorkerSourceTask.java:329)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:166)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:200)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema{"type":"record","name":"Key","namespace":"localdb.test.bins","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"int"}],"connect.name":"localdb.test.bins.Key"}
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.toKafkaException(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:259)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:156)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Serializer.serialize(AvroConverter.java:153)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:86)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Leader not known.; error code: 50004
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:297)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:367)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:544)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:532)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:490)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:257)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:366)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:337)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:115)
    ... 17 more
```

Not sure why Avro serialization is complaining here, also worth to mention when I update the connector configs and amend the below configs to use JSONConverter for the value and StringConverter for the key, everything works fine, not sure what I am missing here.

```
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false"
```

Comment: Is there more to the stacktrace? Why did it fail to register? What are the errors from the schema registry logs?

Comment: @OneCricketeer added the rest of the exception in the question above

Comment: It mentions that RestClientException Leader Not Known

Comment: Are you running multiple instances of the registry server? Can you share its configuration?

Comment: @OneCricketeer single instance, I am running the local confluent for testing before live deployment

Comment: `UnknownTopicOrPartition` would mean your Kafka cluster is unhealthy, or misconfigured for your client(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for my issue was just recreating the local environment from scratch, where the schema-registry exceptions logs are not happening anymore, nothing else related to the connector nor the SMT configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following url:

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/configuration/avro.html#avro-serialization

In the post remark:

" If you want records to be serialized with JSON, consider setting the following connector configuration properties to false:

key.converter.schemas.enable

value.converter.schemas.enable

Setting these properties to false excludes the verbose schema information from each record."

"To use Apache Avro serialization, you must deploy a schema registry that manages Avro message schemas and their versions. Available options include the Apicurio API and Schema Registry as well as the Confluent Schema Registry. Both are described here."

This explains the behaviour.

Comment: Don’t think this the reason, i have already the schema registry connected and the messages serialized correctly without the amr, the issue is why the custom smt failed to serialize the schema in case of avro even if i didn’t change the schema

Comment: Avro always has a schema. These values don't apply. The question is asking specifically about the Avro error

Comment: I also tried to explicitly add the below configurations, but still nothing solid
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"

Comment: I think I found the problem, my schema-registry logs show a weird exception 
`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition` however the server is up and running and reachable via curl

Comment: @KarimTawfik Does it say what topic? Is your _schemas topic healthy? The server's consumer client runs on a separate thread, so the API will always respond

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes it mentions the topic as in the exception `Failed to serialize Avro data from topic localdb.test.bins`, I am debugging why schema-registry is showing exceptions in the logs while it is accessible via api